# Is there a good way to create, derive and manipulate UUID Style by code?

Tags: codenameone

I'd like to dynamically swap certain UUID styles.

Is there a good way to create, derive and manipulate UUID Style by code?

Or is there a good way to replace a UUID by onother one - use template UUIDs?

Comment: Swap with what a set of fixed values or something completely dynamic. If the former there is theme overriding or layering which is discussed in the developer guide https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html